# MySQL: Capture every 5 values from column a in Table A to create one row in Table B

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have submissions of a form from a web page records in a database.
the table has the following schema

`submit_time    form_name   field_name  field_value field_order file`

the form has 5 fields, each form submission results in 5 rows in the previous table, one row per field.
the following is an example of 5 rows created after a submission.

```
    submit_time       form_name     field_name  field_value field_order file
    1427715050.2890 Contact form 1  your-name       Jung            0   NULL
    1427715050.2890 Contact form 1  your-email      Jung@Jung.Jung  1   NULL
    1427715050.2890 Contact form 1  your-subject    Jung maybe :)   2   NULL
    1427715050.2890 Contact form 1  your-message    Jung :D         3   NULL
    1427715050.2890 Contact form 1  Submitted Login Mohammad    9999    NULL
```

I want the data to be written in another table in another database the new table has the following schema:

`Name        email       subject         message         Login`

**What I tried**
I thought about writing a trigger like the following:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER copy_data
    AFTER INSERT
    ON TABLE_A FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    # check if submission entry exists in table B

    # NO :
        # INSERT the data in the corresponding column 

    # YES:
        # UPDATE the data in the corresponding column  

    END
```

but I can't insert NULL values in the second table.

what can I do in such situation ?

**Note:** I can't guarantee the order of the rows in Table A ( which field will be inserted first is something I can't control)

Comment: what happen if the same form (`contact form 1`) are filled from two distinct users at the same time (i.e. 1427715050.2890)? Maybe it is a rare event, but could it happen?

Comment: A very long shot.

Comment: :-) However I think it is better to have an unique id associated to a form submission, and  to have all rows of the first table inserted into unique transaction.

Comment: The insertion into table A is being done by a WordPress plug in, the form is online.

Comment: So, I guess that plug in is handling that case somehow, maybe by just discarding the second user I have no idea. But you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

The TRIGGER can be simplified down to

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

It is not proper to have "redundant" data in a database.  Why can't you just leave it in the original table?  When you need it, do a `JOIN`.

Comment: I agree, it is not proper. But the insertion is done through a WordPress plug in which I can't control it is behavior. Would this solution work? It won't insert null values?

Comment: I'm sorry, I lose patience with 3rd party packages that get in the way.  You have 2 packages -- WP and a plugin.  Complain to them.  Meanwhile, you are having to become an expert in MySQL _just to figure out how to work around their limitations_.

Comment: And since I am not expert enough I turned to the community here, I just need to select a column and make it a row in another table. How remains a mystery :-D